# Footer contents disappeared

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-1.8, php

I've got an urgent issue to resolve, I noticed that the website is missing blog posts used to appear on the bottom left of the page, and we used to have more information/links at the bottom too. For example, “About Us”, “Our Services” etc. but the footer is blank.

I am using Magento CE 1.8.

I have checked under CMS > Static Blocks > footer static 2. Which has got all the info to be displayed. It is already enabled. I have cleared caches, reindexed but nothing is helping.

Also I checked if the identifier value is incorrect, but no that is valid too.

If you go to our store, https://digitales.com.au, you will see the missing things at the bottom.

This is how it use to look before the contents disappeared from footer,

[image]

Someone please help me on this?

Comment: Please check the error logs

Comment: Nothing under error logs.

Comment: What is the last update you made in this website?

Comment: It's back on, I guess the error was with wrong identifier.

Answer (score 0):

It smells like a PHP Fatal Error there, you'd see the concrete error in your web server error logs

If you can't access that logs, maybe this could lead you to fix the problem: view source code & look where the parse of page stops

```
<div class="ma-footer-container">
...
    <div id="popup-wishlist">
        <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Select wishlist or create:</legend>
            <div id="wishlists">
                on tab page
```

You can start by disabling that wishlist popup & see what happens